# tell Java to recognize type with if/else section

Tags: java

I have this section of code:

```
  var v = this.rhs;

  if(this.rhs instanceof String){
    v = ((String)v).replace("'","''");  // escape single-quotes
  }
  else{
    v = v.toString();
  }

  if(v.contains(" ")){
    v = String.join("","'",v,"'");
  }
```

Java complains and says:

[image]

It can't deduce that it must be a String. Although type-systems like TypeScript can deduce this. I am on Java version 10. Is there a way to tell Java that `v` must be type String?

Comment: Since when does Java have the `var` keyword?

Comment: Java version 10 introduced the var keyword

Comment: My Q. is in what occasion v is not String? *

Comment: You already did it in the first clause of the if-else by casting it. Why aren't you doing the same in the else clause?

Comment: there is a way: a cast, you use it in your code. But the else branch of your if shows, that v can't be of type String but is of type Object.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to tell Java that `v` must be type String?

Yes, declare it as a string:

```
String v = "";
```

In each of your conditional blocks, `v` is set to the value of a string.  Since it's always going to be a string, and as you say it must be a string, then simply make it a `String` in the first place.

There doesn't seem to be any value in setting `v` to `this.rhs`.  Just directly use `this.rhs` in your conditional blocks:

```
v = ((String)this.rhs).replace("'","''");
//...
v = this.rhs.toString();
```